# redux form - how can i show input before click add button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I tried this tutorial: https://redux-form.com/6.1.1/examples/fieldarrays/ but I want to show "first name" and "last name" inputs before clicking the "add member" button. I mean, when the page is first opened, the two inputs will already be shown and the user will press the button whenever the user wants to add extra input. how can I do that?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import validate from './validate'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const renderMembers = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Member</button>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </li>
    {fields.map((member, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Member"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
        <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.firstName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="First Name"/>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.lastName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Last Name"/>
        <FieldArray name={`${member}.hobbies`} component={renderHobbies}/>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
)

const renderHobbies = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add Hobby</button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((hobby, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Hobby"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
        <Field
          name={hobby}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}/>
      </li>
    )}
    {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
  </ul>
)

const FieldArraysForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="clubName" type="text" component={renderField} label="Club Name"/>
      <FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembers}/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'fieldArrays',     // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(FieldArraysForm)
```

Comment: As you say you are following the tutorial: you are aware that it is generally not recommended any more (for years) to have [form state in redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux) and the author of redux-form advises against using it for new projects [on the project's start page](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/) (also, you are following a tutorial for a very old version of redux-form there).

Just want that you aren't just getting started and running into a wrong direction there.

Comment: Actually, i used the last version but i gave the wrong link. Although it is not recommended to use it, I think my question still has an answer. @phry

Comment: Sure, but as I don't use it, I don't give you that answer. And seeing that  even the library author recommends against using it for years now, probably not too many people will still be around to give you that answer. But good luck, I hope you find someone :)

I just wanted to make you aware of the general fact since unfortunately, there are still a lot of tutorials about that teach redux-form and many newcomers to redux still fall for those outdated tutorials.

Comment: In the project I was involved in, redux-form was used before, so I didn't want to break this structure. Thank you for your advice :)